# what is the command that would only print or extract a file's UPPERCASE characters and date time in a string

Tags: linux

what is the command that would only print or extract a file's UPPERCASE characters and date time in a string.

ex.

**BLACKSHEEP** +61247869526 **2020-05-01** **7:75** at workstation x.

The supervisor of blacksheep did not report to the office today.

The manager of the supervisor is also on leave today.

**WILDLION** +61247869526 **2020-05-02** **12:45** at workstation y.

The supervisor of Wildlion did not report to the office today.

The manager of the supervisor is also on leave today.

I wanted to get all the uppercases (BLACKSHEEP, WILDLION) characters and the date and time (2020-05-01 7:75, 2020-05-02 12:45)

hope you will be able to help me out on this.

Comment: Hi, welcome so SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve].  That being said, the `sed` command with `s///` and regular expressions (re) could be used to do that. 
 You would use 1 re for the cap letters, another for the date (which are numbers, - and ; in a specific sequence).

Comment: @Dukot Bahaw - What do you mean by _print …  in a string_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) by matching alternatively the uppercase name (forming a whole word, `-w`) or the timestamp:

```
grep -woE '[A-Z]{2,}|[0-9]+-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]+:[0-9]{2}' file
```